# Found reliance on default encoding in FileReader

Tags: java, findbugs

How can we fix the below issue reported by findBugs:

```
Found reliance on default encoding in abc.java : new java.io.FileReader(File)
```

I'm just reading file & Findbug has reported the issue.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use an explicit character encoding when opening a file instead of relying on the platform default (which can change depending on the platform), unless of course, you intend to use the platform default.  you can use `InputStreamReader` to convert a `FileInputStream` to a `Reader` using an explicit character encoding.

Comment: Can you provide some code snippet?

Comment: @Mike - a quick google search for "java FileReader character encoding" found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696626/java-filereader-encoding-issue)

Comment: `InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(targetFile);
    Reader fileReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");` is working.