# ArrayIndexOutofBoundException when printing unicode words in jtext area. (Malayalam Words)

Tags: java, swing, unicode, jtextarea, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to print malayalam words fetched from rssfeeds provided by various medias like "Matrubhumi" "Indiavision" to a jtext area.

What I am doing is saving all the topics from rssfeed to a text file and then reading them line by line to print it into a textarea. But at some words I am getting `ArrayIndexOutofBoundException`.

For example printing "ബോസ്റ്റണ്‍ സംഭവം: അമേരിക്കയിലെ സിഖ് സമൂഹം ആശങ്കയില്‍ " gives the error.
Please point out any mistakes I am making. Also I have changed font to "Meera" so I do not think it is the problem. Also strings like " ബംഗാളില്‍ ചിട്ടി കമ്പനി പൊളിഞ്ഞു, സംഘര്‍ഷം " do not show any error and opens the application window. Thanks in advance.

```
  BufferedReader demo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Name));
  jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
  jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
  setBackground(java.awt.Color.white);
  setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1366, 768));
  jTextArea1.setColumns(30);
  jTextArea1.setRows(10);
  jTextArea1.setBorder(null);
  jTextArea1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Meera", 1, 24));
  jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
  jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);
  jTextArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
  jTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);
    while ((sCurrentLine = demo.readLine()) != null){
    jTextArea1.append(sCurrentLine);
}
  private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
  public static final java.lang.Character.UnicodeBlock MALAYALAM = null;
```

The rest of the code is auto generated code from netbeans.
This is the second class. The main class deals with fetching rssfeed and saving the topics into a text file. And the name of the text file is passed to this class where `FileReader()` is used to gain access to the file and fetch the contents line by line to a string variable "sCurrentLine". And using `jTextArea.append()` append the text into the text area.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 432
at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.createCharinfo(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:772)
at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.getCharinfo(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:509)
at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.getLineBreakIndex(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:455)
at java.awt.font.TextMeasurer.calcLineBreak(TextMeasurer.java:325)
at java.awt.font.TextMeasurer.getLineBreakIndex(TextMeasurer.java:561)
at java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer.nextOffset(LineBreakMeasurer.java:358)
at java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer.nextLayout(LineBreakMeasurer.java:440)
at javax.swing.text.TextLayoutStrategy.sync(TextLayoutStrategy.java:323)
at javax.swing.text.TextLayoutStrategy.insertUpdate(TextLayoutStrategy.java:70)
at javax.swing.text.FlowView.loadChildren(FlowView.java:143)
at javax.swing.text.CompositeView.setParent(CompositeView.java:139)
at javax.swing.text.FlowView.setParent(FlowView.java:289)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextAreaUI$PlainParagraph.setParent(BasicTextAreaUI.java:239)
at javax.swing.text.CompositeView.replace(CompositeView.java:217)
at javax.swing.text.BoxView.replace(BoxView.java:181)
at javax.swing.text.View.updateChildren(View.java:1116)
at javax.swing.text.View.insertUpdate(View.java:700)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.insertUpdate(BasicTextUI.java:1602)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler.insertUpdate(BasicTextUI.java:1861)
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(AbstractDocument.java:202)
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(AbstractDocument.java:749)
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(AbstractDocument.java:708)
at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(PlainDocument.java:130)
at javax.swing.JTextArea.append(JTextArea.java:477)
```

Also I tried to run the program by enclosing the error generatingportion in a try catch, but then i got another `ArrayIndexOutofBoundException` but this time at a diffrent line.Code Segment

```
 String RSSName;
 RSSName = "Matrubhumi";
 ReadTest demo = new ReadTest();
 demo.NewsFeed(RSSName); //Creates text file and fetch data from rssfeed
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
 frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 frame.add(new ImportantNews(RSSName),BorderLayout.CENTER);
 frame.setSize(1366, 768);
 frame.setVisible(true); // new exception is thrown in this line
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 



 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 496
at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.createCharinfo(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:772)
at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.getCharinfo(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:509)
at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.getCharX(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:353)
at java.awt.font.TextLine$3.computeFunction(TextLine.java:515)
at java.awt.font.TextLine.applyFunctionAtIndex(TextLine.java:651)
at java.awt.font.TextLine.getCharXPosition(TextLine.java:668)
at java.awt.font.TextLine.getCharLinePosition(TextLine.java:678)
at java.awt.font.TextLayout.buildCache(TextLayout.java:683)
at java.awt.font.TextLayout.ensureCache(TextLayout.java:655)
at java.awt.font.TextLayout.getAdvance(TextLayout.java:885)
at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.charsWidth(FontDesignMetrics.java:510)
at javax.swing.text.Utilities.getTabbedTextWidth(Utilities.java:279)
at javax.swing.text.GlyphPainter1.getSpan(GlyphPainter1.java:62)
at javax.swing.text.GlyphView.getPreferredSpan(GlyphView.java:592)
at javax.swing.text.View.getMaximumSpan(View.java:269)
at javax.swing.text.ParagraphView.findEdgeSpan(ParagraphView.java:768)
at javax.swing.text.ParagraphView.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(ParagraphView.java:736)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextAreaUI$PlainParagraph.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(BasicTextAreaUI.java:272)
at javax.swing.text.BoxView.checkRequests(BoxView.java:935)
at javax.swing.text.BoxView.getMinimumSpan(BoxView.java:568)
at javax.swing.text.BoxView.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(BoxView.java:903)
at javax.swing.text.BoxView.checkRequests(BoxView.java:935)
at javax.swing.text.BoxView.setSpanOnAxis(BoxView.java:343)
at javax.swing.text.BoxView.layout(BoxView.java:708)
at javax.swing.text.BoxView.setSize(BoxView.java:397)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.setSize(BasicTextUI.java:1714)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.getPreferredSize(BasicTextUI.java:917)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextAreaUI.getPreferredSize(BasicTextAreaUI.java:120)
at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1651)
at javax.swing.JTextArea.getPreferredSize(JTextArea.java:619)
at javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout.layoutContainer(ScrollPaneLayout.java:790)
at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1503)
at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1492)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1688)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1697)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1697)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1697)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1697)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1697)
at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1623)
at java.awt.Container.validateUnconditionally(Container.java:1660)
at java.awt.Window.show(Window.java:1033)
at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1651)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1603)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the exception on?

Comment: When appending into Jtextarea.

Comment: Please post a stack trace.

Comment: Hey Arun, have you found a solution to this issue? I'm getting this exact problem with letters പ്റ്റ and സ്റ്റ.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an encoding issue as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696626/java-filereader-encoding-issue)

Try replacing this line

```
BufferedReader demo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Name));
```

with

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), encoding));
```

where `encoding` should be the encoding used in the file you're storing your topics in.

Comment: Thanks for that fast reply. But I still got the same error when I ran the program after doing the changes u said...

Comment: There seems to be a bug report about this: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=8b833c54cb93d6c9cf416667dc02?bug_id=6374477