# Java Encoding Error

Tags: java, encoding

I am trying to take a string encoded and saved in Cp1252 encoding and display it in a java text area.  When i read it back it has black diamonds with question marks where special characters normally are (', &, etc).  What should i do to format it to display the proper characters.

I cant copy and paste the text as it displays almost properly when moved out of word.  But the code i am using to read the Cp1252 file is below:

```
try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        //Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            emi.stringContent += "\n" + strLine;
        }

    br.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EMailTmpDirRead.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EMailTmpDirRead.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Thanks!

Made the following edits and now nothing reads in.

```
StringBuffer temp2 = new StringBuffer(1000);
    int numRead = 0;
    char[] buf = new char[1024];

    try {
        ir = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f), "Cp1252");
        while((numRead = ir.read()) != -1)
        {
            String temp = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);
            temp2.append(temp);
            buf = new char[1024];
        }
        emi.stringContent = temp2.toString();
```

Lines appear to be skipped
    StringBuffer temp2 = new StringBuffer();

```
    try {
        ir = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f), "Cp1252");
        br = new BufferedReader(ir);
        while(br.readLine() != null)
        {
            temp2.append(br.readLine());
        }
        emi.stringContent = temp2.toString();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java FileReader encoding issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696626/java-filereader-encoding-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a `FileReader`, use a `FileInputStream` wrapped with an `InputStreamReader`; specify the character encoding in the InputStreamReader's constructor (according to [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) it looks like you should use "Cp1252" for the encoding)

Comment: Try wrapping the `InputStreamReader` in a [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), and use the BufferedReader's `readLine()` method in the loop (terminating the loop when `readLine()` reads a null).

Comment: that works but i lose all formatting...i need to keep the formatting

Comment: You're skipping every other line of text - br.readLine() consumes a line of text, so the br.readLine() statement in the loop header is discarding lines of text.  Change this to `String tempStr; while((tempStr = br.readLine()) != null) { temp2.append(tempStr); }`