# Java printing stray character instead of actual

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filewriter, printwriter

I have a simple java program that reads a line from file and writes it to another file.

My source file has words like: `it's` but the destination file is having words like `it�s`.

I am using `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));` to read the source file and `PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(resultFile, "UTF-8");` to write the destination file.

How to get the actual character in my destination file too?

Comment: You are probably using the wrong charset to read the file; given that you don't specify one, it is the JVM's default which will be used (which is implementation- and platform-dependent).

Comment: then how to deal with it to get the correct copying?

Comment: Use the appropriate `FileReader` constructor as mentioned in the answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java FileReader encoding issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696626/java-filereader-encoding-issue)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a CharacterSet when creating the BufferedReader, otherwise the platform default encoding is used:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile),"UTF-8");
```

Comment: Using Java 7 this can be written `Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(inputFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Comment: I tried as mentioned in answer, but it is giving error `Incompatible type: string can not be converted into int`

Comment: At what line does that exception occur? Could you add more of your code (i.e. the method, which performs the reading and writing) in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old, but I thought I'd put down my answer anyway.

You can use java.nio.file.Files to read the file and java.io.RandomAccessFile to write to your destination file. For example:

```
public void copyContentsOfFile(File source, File destination){
    Path p = Paths.get(source.toURI());
    try {
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(p);
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(destination, "rw");
        raf.writeBytes(new String(bytes));
        raf.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```