# Saving an image returned by an API in JSON

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpeg, httpresponse

I am using a [Meme generator API](https://rapidapi.com/ronreiter/api/meme-generator). My goal is to generate memes with the API , be able to view and save them as JPG images.

When I try to use the Java code provided by the creator, I get an error message.

Here's the provided code that fails:

```
  HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("https://ronreiter-meme-generator.p.rapidapi.com/meme?font=Impact&font_size=50&meme=Condescending-Wonka&top=Yolo&bottom=HA")
      .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", "TOP_SECRET")
      .asJson();
```

The error message:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'APIController' defined in file
>   [C:\yaml\out\production\classes\com\example\demo\controllers\APIController.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'APIService' defined in file
>   [C:\yaml\out\production\classes\com\example\demo\services\APIService.class]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.example.demo.services.APIService]: Constructor threw
>   exception; nested exception is
>   com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1
>   [character 2 line 1]

It says the field

```
response
```

cannot be parsed as a JSONArray, so I tried this code snippet instead:

```
  HttpResponse<String> meme = Unirest.get("https://ronreiter-meme-generator.p.rapidapi.com/meme?font=Impact&font_size=50&meme=Impossibru-Guy-Original&top=Random+meme&bottom=Bottom+text")
      .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", "TOP_SECRET")
      .asString();
```

In this case the code runs, but as I call the endpoint, I get loads of

> ufffd

snippets in the String, which basically means that I am trying to read a code which has no representation in Unicode. I've seen a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493220/why-is-my-string-returning-ufffd-ufffdn-a-m-e) how I could deal with this problem but I'm not pretty sure I'm going on a right way.

According to website, on which the API is provided, I should get something like this as a response:

[image]

Could you give me any pieces of advice how to approach this problem?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Advice: Ask yourself why you want to return a jpeg image as a String or in json? Easiest way to return a jpg is as a jpeg, just write the raw jpg to a file or to the output stream or wherever you want to send it. You can turn a jpeg into json using, say, Base64 encoding, but a browser client will not know how to display it. So usually better to save and return it as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I could sort out the problem with some help.
Here it is:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = Unirest.get("https://ronreiter-meme-generator.p.rapidapi.com/meme?font=Impact&font_size=50&meme=Condescending-Wonka&top=Top+text&bottom=Bottom+text")
        .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", "YOUR_SECRET_API_KEY")
        .asBinary();
InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getRawBody();
BufferedImage imBuff = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
String filePath = "C:/x/x.jpg";
File file = new File(filePath);
ImageIO.write(imBuff, "jpg", file);
```

So here are the points to do:

1. Retrieve the response as binary data
2. Transform it to an InputStream
3. Create a BufferedImage from it
4. Create a File with the specified filePath
5. Write the BufferedImage into the FIle

Answer (score 1):

The content-type of your API specification contains "image/jpeg".
This means that the response does not contain JSON, but binary image data, so trying to parse it as JSON will result in failure.

Try saving the response from your API directly to a file, you'll see that it's an image.