# How to verify the invalid unicode code point value?

Tags: go

In the below code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := []rune{'\u0041', '\u0042', '\u0043', '\u20AC', -1}
    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println(string(s)) // ABC€�
    fmt.Println(s[3] == '€')
    fmt.Println(s[4] == '�')
    fmt.Println(s[4] == '\uFFFD')
}
```

---

input stream has invalid unicode code point -1 that gets stored as `\uFFFD`.

But below lines are giving output as `false`:

```
    fmt.Println(s[4] == '�')
    fmt.Println(s[4] == '\uFFFD')
```

How to verify the unicode code point values outside the range of valid unicode code points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
slice1 := []rune{'\u0041', '\u0042', '\u0043', '\u20AC', -1}
st := string(slice1)
slice2 := []rune(st)
fmt.Println(slice2[4] == '\uFFFD') // true
```

Since `s[4]` is `-1` as a result `s[4] == '\uFFFD'` is false.
`'\uFFFD'` is the `ReplacementChar` which represents invalid code points.
and is the replacement for invalid code points, e.g. `-1`, using `string([]rune{'A', -1})` replaces `-1` with `'\uFFFD'`, try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/jLlyLH3UHFD):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(unicode.ReplacementChar)
    fmt.Println(utf8.ValidRune(unicode.ReplacementChar))

    rs := []rune{'A', -1}
    s := string(rs)
    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println([]rune(s)) //[65 65533]
}
```

---

[ValidRune](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#ValidRune)

```
func ValidRune(r rune) bool
```

ValidRune reports whether r can be legally encoded as UTF-8. Code points that are out of range or a surrogate half are illegal.

```
const (
    surrogateMin = 0xD800
    surrogateMax = 0xDFFF
    MaxRune   = '\U0010FFFF' // Maximum valid Unicode code point.
)
// ValidRune reports whether r can be legally encoded as UTF-8.
// Code points that are out of range or a surrogate half are illegal.
func ValidRune(r rune) bool {
    switch {
    case 0 <= r && r < surrogateMin:
        return true
    case surrogateMax < r && r <= MaxRune:
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    slice := []rune{'\u0041', '\u0042', '\u0043', '\u20AC', '\uFFFD', 0xfffffff, -1}
    for i, v := range slice {
        fmt.Printf("%d %q %v\n", i, v, utf8.ValidRune(v))
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0 'A' true
1 'B' true
2 'C' true
3 '€' true
4 '�' true
5 %!q(int32=268435455) false
6 %!q(int32=-1) false
```

See:
[Why is my String returning "\ufffd\ufffdN a m e"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493220/why-is-my-string-returning-ufffd-ufffdn-a-m-e)

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21975