# Reading from a file Russian characters(javaSE)

Tags: java, regex, bufferedreader

Following code works with file having English content perfectly but not with Russian content. How to make it work for Russian as well?

```
try(BufferedReader fileOut = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))){

        for(String line; (line = fileOut.readLine()) != null; ){
            if(line.contains(commandString)) 
                System.out.println(count + ": " + line);
            count++;
        }

    }
```

**UPD:**

I tried to write: this only works when the line contains one word then outputs, for example: "привет" If a line contains more than one word is no output, for example "привет как дела"

```
 new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "Cp1251"))
```

p.s: thank very much for answers

Comment: Maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696626/java-filereader-encoding-issue

Comment: My first guess would be the code page of the `commandString` value does not match that of the file contents. You should probably provide some more information, such as sample data.

Comment: What character encoding is the file using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the encoding to be able to read the russian character. Don't use `FileReader` as it will use default platform encoding.

Instead use

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileDir), "UTF8");
```

Comment: I tried to write: this only works when the line contains one word then outputs, for example: "привет" If a line contains more than one word is no output, for example "привет как дела" **new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "Cp1251"))**

Answer (score 0):

Use below method to read file content of any file in any language.
I have made a FileUtil.java and this method is a part of it. Its handy and works well...

And the key to the working code is **charset**:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"))
```

Whole method is below:

```
public static String getFileContent(File file) throws IOException
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"))) {

            String sCurrentLine;

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                sb.append(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```