# Reading from a file doesn't get the expected text

Tags: java, file, char, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read a config for a sudoku type game from a file, line by line, and then separate the line into useable data.

**However, when I try to save it as a string, the lines with a '÷' show up strangely**

```
if (file != null && file.exists() && file.canRead()) {
try {
    //For each line manipulate the data for processing
    BufferedReader buffered = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String currentLine;
    while((currentLine = buffered.readLine()) != null) {
        target = currentLine.split(" ")[0];
        System.out.println(target);
        ids = (currentLine.split(" ")[1]).split(",");
        .....
    }
    buffered.close();
```

The first two lines of the file are:

> 11+ 1,7

and

> 2÷ 2,3

The result of my debugging print statement is:

```
11+
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2Ã"
2Ã·
```

So I believe the ÷ is showing up as Ã for some reason.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodoku - perhaps you mean "Sudoku"? ;)

Comment: You're reading using the wrong character set.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/696641/611819) to "Java FileReader encoding issue"